# How can I order by many-to-many extra column in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 3. `Member` and `Request` entities are related many-to-many. But I have an extra column named `Order`. The member request order is saved in the `MemberRequest` table.

```
    public class Member
    {
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MemberRequest> MemberRequests { get; set; }
    }

    public class Request
    {
        public int RequestID { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MemberRequest> MemberRequests { get; set; }
    }

    public class MemberRequest
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int RequestID { get; set; }

        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
        public virtual Request Request { get; set; }

        public int Order { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to get two select using Entity Framework Core:

```
    public IEnumerable<Member> Get(int id)
    {
        var members = await _context.Request
            .Include(e => e.MemberRequests)
            .Where(e => e.MemberRequests.Any(m => m.RequestID == id))
            .ToListAsync();
            
        // How can I order by MemberRequest.Order ???
        
        return member;
    }
```

But I could not order result by `MemberRequest.Order` in `MemberRequest` entity. How can I do it?

Comment: There might be multiple MemberRequests associated with the Request, how the system should decide which one to take? Think in terms of SQL, what's the query you would like to be generated?